# Making the range of perlin noise smaller

Tags: java, terrain, perlin-noise

I have a perlin noise function, and I want to use it to pick biomes for a map for my game. The problem is that biomes are determined by two factors - average precipitation and average temperature. So, I thought, I'd just make two perlin noise functions and overlap them.

The issue now is that biomes do not encompass all possible precipitation temperature combinations. For example, there is no biome with high precipitation and low temperature, as shown in this picture.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/29/PrecipitationTempBiomes.jpg))</sub>

How can I still use perlin noise but never reach the areas that aren't covered by biomes?

Comment: The easiest solution is just to re-roll Perlin noise (with slightly changed values, obviously) any time you don't hit within the map. Not sure what that'll do to your total distribution of points though. And it may take a while to get out of that "bad" area.

Comment: Yes, the safest thing to do is just discard any results that fall outside the allowable area.

Answer (score 1):

You can clamp the values into the allowed range (eg. maximum allowed precipitation in an area with temperature 0 °C is 100 cm).

You can do this during the noise algorithm itself, not only after the entire value field is finished. I would imagine it would work like this:

- First generate the temperature map.
- When you are generating each random value for the rainfall noise, generate a value in range scaled down appropriately to the range of values allowed by the temperature map.

Example:
If you would generate random value in range 0 - 250 mm (about 50% of maximum possible rainfall, for one of the low frequency noise layers), look at the temperature in that pixel, see it's 10 °C, so the range of the random value will be scaled down to 0-100mm (50% of the 0-200 mm allowed by that temperature).

Therefore, even if you roll maximum random value for each of the layers, the composite value will be restricted by the maximum dictated by the temperature.

I don't know how realistic this is and how important realism is for you. What precisely prevents low temperature areas from having great rainfall? The solution I proposed might actually simulate factors like reduced evaporation in low temperature areas quite well.

EDIT:

One more idea, which might end up being equivalent to my first solution:

- Generate both the temperature map and rainfall map independently.
- Multiply the rainfall map by the temperature map (scaled to range <0, 1>). This will reduce rainfall in areas with low temperature.